# React unable to use response to GET request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I was working on the frontend of a webapp using React and came across a strange problem when processing the call's response.

I make the call like this:

```
async getNumStudents() {
    const n = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/students',
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response => response.json())
          .then((responseJSON) => responseJSON.length);
    console.log(typeof(n));
    console.log(n);
    this.setState({numStudents: n})
    //return n;
}
```

The response seems to come in perfectly according to the `console.log()`s, with the `typeof()` returning "number" and the JSON displaying as it should in the second, however if I try to either return n or assign it to the state an `[object Promise]` is returned.

I would expect this if I did not include the `await` but I am not sure why a the value would seemingly become a promise when it exits the function.

For reference, the Java code for this endpoint looks like this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@GetMapping("/students")
public List<Student> getAllStudents() { return studentRepository.findAll(); }
```

Thanks in advance for any advice you might have!

Answer (score 0):

did you also call getNumStudents() like this :

```js
await getNumStudents()
```

Comment: I haven't been able to since neither ```componentDidMount()``` nor ```render()```, where the function would be called, can be made async as far as I know. Is there another way to call it that I am missing?